# Go to certain website when item from combo box is selected

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to create a combo box with multiple items. When an item is selected and the button is clicked it will take you to a website. Each item in the combo box leads to a different website. I have searched with no luck finding the results I need. Any help would be appreciated. My code this far is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tools
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tools.Items.Add("Movies");
            tools.Items.Add("Music");
            tools.Items.Add("Documents");
            tools.Items.Add("Apps");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button click event evaluate the selected value and send to the desired site.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tools.Items.Add("Movies");
        tools.Items.Add("Music");
        tools.Items.Add("Documents");
        tools.Items.Add("Apps");

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(tools.SelectedValue)
        {
            "Movies":
                      Response.Redirect("google.com");
                       break;
            "Music":
                      Response.Redirect("google.com");
                       break;
            "Documents":
                      Response.Redirect("google.com");
                       break;
            "Apps":
                      Response.Redirect("google.com");
                       break;


         }
    }
```

Comment: I think better create a list of urls. And then when button clicked, we can redirect to urls[todos.SelectedIndex]. So that in future we can add new url easily.

Comment: @kienct89 I agree with you